# ISO duration with Java script

Tags: javascript, iso8601

I apologize for the question because I have already posted a similar question, but I would like to know how I can do the following conversion:

```
PT11H9M38.7876754S
```

I want to disable seconds and only show hour and minutes 11:09

When I have time displays minutes from 1 to 9, I want to add a 0 in front of number

Tnx in advice...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var str = 'PT11H9M38.7876754S'
    match = str.match(/(\d*)H(\d*)M/),
    formatted = match[1] + ':' + (!match[2][1] ? 0 + match[2] : match[2]);

console.log(formatted);  // => 11:09
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"PT11H9M38.78767545".replace(/PT(\d+)H(\d+)M.*/,function(m,a,b) {return a+":"+(b.length<2?"0":"")+b;});
```

One-liner :p

Comment: Hmmm, that's what minifiers do. Why wouldn't you format your code?

Answer (score 1):

Since all the nice **RegExp** stuff is above here is a third solution a bit more expensive in terms of parsing but you may be looking for something different.

You can use the `split` function to parse the string and extract the portions that you need.

```
var pt="PT11H9M38.7876754S";

function showtime(s){
    var time = s.split('.');
    var hours = time[0].split('T')[1].split('H')[0];
    var minutes = time[0].split('H')[1].split('M')[0];
    return digitize(hours) + ":" + digitize(minutes) 
}

function digitize(i){
    return (i>9) ? i : "0" + i; 
}


alert(showtime(pt)); // 11:09
```